# What font is used widely for mobile app ui mockups?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, android, google-material-design

I need to design a UI/UX interface for my Android application, and I have been surfing the web for inspiration, from mockups and other design concepts.

I have noticed that a vast majority of mobile app ui mockups/design concepts use a specific font.

Can you help me identify the font used?

Here are some links which contain the app examples with the font used:

1. https://dribbble.com/shots/2058811-Wave-Music-App/attachments/367979
2. https://dribbble.com/shots/2095295-Walkthrough-Screens

This font that I am looking for has also been used in Invision's DO UI kit...

Also, would you guys tell me if it is OK to use this font in an Android app, which might also use Material Design? I am trying to make a music app, and the Roboto font does not seem to go well.

Thanks in advance!
P.S. I am new to Graphic Design stack exchange, so if there is anything I did wrong, pls tell me!

Answer (score 1):

Any "sans serif" font can be used mostly. because they are legible and they look very clean in mobile screens. Typefaces with a bit larger x-height works even more better.

It is not like 2 or three kind of typefaces can be used for mobile screens. There are lot of typefaces which suits well.

Check [this article](http://superdevresources.com/best-free-sans-serif-fonts-2014/) for some best sans serif fonts.

Answer (score 0):

> https://dribbble.com/shots/2058811-Wave-Music-App/attachments/367979

Museo Sans or Museo Sans Rounded. The give aways are `Jugo 45` and `Running & Workout` (the J, R and &).

> https://dribbble.com/shots/2095295-Walkthrough-Screens

Could be Proxima Nova. R, y match pretty well, but a looks different.